# "Invalid keystore format" on setting keystore for type "JCEKS" for symmetric key encryption

Tags: encryption, java-8, encryption-symmetric, jetty-9, iaik-jce

I am trying to use symmetric encryption for securing the communication on jetty-9 using java-8.
The cipher suite for this purpose I am using is "TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256". The implementation for this cipher suite is provided by third party provider - "IAIK".

Since its symmetric encryption, the keystore type I am using is "JCEKS" and not default i.e. "JKS".

On trying to configure this keystore, I am getting this error - java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format.

The program code is as follows:

```
import iaik.security.provider.IAIK;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.Security;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Connector;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConfiguration;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnectionFactory;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.SecureRequestCustomizer;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.SslConnectionFactory;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory;

public class TestJettyServer {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory();
    sslContextFactory.setIncludeProtocols(new String[] { "TLSv1" });
    Security.addProvider(new IAIK()); // third party provider for cipher suite "TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256"
    sslContextFactory.setIncludeCipherSuites(new String[] { "TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256" });

    attachSymmetricKeyStore(sslContextFactory);

    HttpConfiguration https = new HttpConfiguration();
    https.addCustomizer(new SecureRequestCustomizer());

    Server server = new Server();

    ServerConnector sslConnector = new ServerConnector(server, new SslConnectionFactory(sslContextFactory, "http/1.1"),
        new HttpConnectionFactory(https));

    sslConnector.setPort(9997);

    Connector[] connectors = { sslConnector };
    server.setConnectors(connectors);

    ServletHandler handler = new ServletHandler();
    server.setHandler(handler);
    handler.addServletWithMapping(HelloServlet.class, "/*");

    server.start();
    server.join();

  }

  private static void attachSymmetricKeyStore(SslContextFactory sslContextFactory) {
    // keystore is generated using following command :
    // keytool -genseckey -alias srccodes -keyalg AES -keystore keystoreAES.jceks -keysize 256 -storeType JCEKS

    sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePath(MinimalServlets.class.getResource("/keystoreAES.jceks").toExternalForm());
    sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePassword("123456");
    sslContextFactory.setKeyManagerPassword("123456");
  }

  public static class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {

    /** The serialVersionUID. */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
      response.setContentType("text/html");
      response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
      response.getWriter().println("<h1>Hello SimpleServlet</h1>");
    }
  }

}
```

The trace is as follows:

```
2014-12-17 19:59:56.506:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.1.v20140609
2014-12-17 19:59:56.539:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:main: FAILED SslContextFactory@12bb4df8(file:/D:/RA_Workspace/JettyWithCipherSuites/bin/keystoreAES.jceks,file:/D:/RA_Workspace/JettyWithCipherSuites/bin/keystoreAES.jceks): java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:650)
at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:55)
at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1433)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.CertificateUtils.getKeyStore(CertificateUtils.java:55)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.loadKeyStore(SslContextFactory.java:864)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.doStart(SslContextFactory.java:270)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.SslConnectionFactory.doStart(SslConnectionFactory.java:64)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:260)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:81)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:218)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:336)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at TestJettyServer.main(TestJettyServer.java:48)
2014-12-17 19:59:56.539:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:main: FAILED SslConnectionFactory@4cc77c2e{SSL-http/1.1}: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:650)
at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:55)
at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1433)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.CertificateUtils.getKeyStore(CertificateUtils.java:55)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.loadKeyStore(SslContextFactory.java:864)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.doStart(SslContextFactory.java:270)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.SslConnectionFactory.doStart(SslConnectionFactory.java:64)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:260)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:81)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:218)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:336)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at TestJettyServer.main(TestJettyServer.java:48)
2014-12-17 19:59:56.539:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:main: FAILED ServerConnector@7a7b0070{SSL-http/1.1}{0.0.0.0:9997}: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:650)
at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:55)
at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1433)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.CertificateUtils.getKeyStore(CertificateUtils.java:55)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.loadKeyStore(SslContextFactory.java:864)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.doStart(SslContextFactory.java:270)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.SslConnectionFactory.doStart(SslConnectionFactory.java:64)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:260)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:81)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:218)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:336)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at TestJettyServer.main(TestJettyServer.java:48)
2014-12-17 19:59:56.539:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:main: FAILED org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@39a054a5: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:650)
at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:55)
at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1433)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.CertificateUtils.getKeyStore(CertificateUtils.java:55)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.loadKeyStore(SslContextFactory.java:864)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.doStart(SslContextFactory.java:270)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.SslConnectionFactory.doStart(SslConnectionFactory.java:64)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:260)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:81)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:218)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:336)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at TestJettyServer.main(TestJettyServer.java:48)
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:650)
at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:55)
at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1433)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.CertificateUtils.getKeyStore(CertificateUtils.java:55)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.loadKeyStore(SslContextFactory.java:864)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.doStart(SslContextFactory.java:270)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.SslConnectionFactory.doStart(SslConnectionFactory.java:64)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:260)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:81)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:218)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:336)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at TestJettyServer.main(TestJettyServer.java:48)
```

How can I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using any other Keystore format other than "JKS", you need to set the Keystore type as "JCEKS" using:

```
sslContextFactory.setKeyStoreType("JCEKS");
```

The default Keystore type for *org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory* is "JKS"